# printing algo : Hex array printf break when value[index] = 0x00

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I want to print big arrays which can contain any value, when 0x00 came then printf stop printing remaining characters.

```
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char string[10]={0x31, 'a', 0x33,0x34, 0x35, 0x00,0x39, 0x40, 0x42,'\0'};
    printf("%.*s\n", 5, string);
    printf("%.*s\n", 10, string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :
1a345
1a345

Note : I can print char by char and it works but it is too slow when dealing in MBs

Comment: `%s` prints everything until a zero. And `0x00 == 0 == '\0'`.

Comment: A C string terminates at the first `0x00` it finds (working from left to right).  You should have learnt that in your first day of C training.  What is the difference between `0x00` and `\0` do you think?

Comment: What did you expect a `%s` format to print when it encountered `0x00` ? Clearly not `00`; your other values are already adjusted for offset to ascii `'0'`; you need to so the same for `0x00` (the usefulness of any of this notwithstanding). Or use a loop and a lookup table.

Comment: Perhaps you can use %X format specifier, that isn’t print hex values.

Comment: Problem will be still there that I have to print each hex value that cause code to be too slow when dealing in MBs

Comment: @user2071394 : have you actually tried that ? A few MB's of data is not a lot, even when processing byte by byte.

Comment: The naming is wrong, a **string** in C ends with a 0 byte *by definition*. That said, you can output any data with a given length using `fwrite()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try to use `fwrite` to simply write a block of data to either a file or stdout. But note, when writing to stdout the zero will not be shown, because cmd/terminal don't have a character assigned to it (as far as I know).

```
fwrite (string , sizeof(char), sizeof(string), stdout);
```

If you write to a file, the data (even the zeros) should be printed to your file and stored, so that should not be an issue if you wish to reuse it later.

Comment: I think writing null bytes to a text stream is not well-defined  , that might be an issue on some systems (particularly Windows ones)

Comment: That is possible, it works fine on Linux, it just skips the character, I'd assume it won't crash cmd either. But I'm assuming he wants to print this to a file in the end, it wouldn't make much sense to print random hex to stdout, it's completely unreadable.